# IC thermal breakdown

Tags: operational-amplifier, thermal

Why does my power op amp IC ([TI OPA549](http://www.ti.com/product/OPA549)) thermally malfunction? IC works **electrically** perfectly, no oscillations or anything. By thermal malfunction I mean that Rj-c thermal impedance rises from default value (1.4°C/W) to about 6...7°C/W.

**What kind of mechanism can cause such malfunction?**

PCB has three **identical** channels (A, B, C) where two of them work flawlessly (B, C) but one (A) constantly malfunctions after short time of use (I have tried three chips).

Below you can see IC and its three important spots center (red), edge (green) and case (blue). With maximium stress ( ~ 40W), channels heat up as follows (measured with thermal camera):

- Working ones:
  70°C (red), 55°C (green), 40°C (blue)
- Malfunctioning:
  +100°C* (red), 59°C (green), 40°C (blue)
  **throttling, junction temperature reaches 150°C limit and stops.*

[image: IC thermal spots]

Thing I have considered:

- soldering: I have always screwed the case to the heatsink and after that carefully soldered the pins.
- mechanical stress: Heatsink is heavy, but firmly attached to PCB.
- case temperature is always same (40°C), so I can assume that the heatsink is working alright.
- B and C channels are working flawlessly as I have designed.

---

**Update: 29 June 2017**

As Chupacabras brought up, I have noticed that problem has something to do with the Vcc line.

I previously had a common heatsink for all channels, but then I installed individual heatsinks for each chip. This had unexpected results:

- C channel works flawlessly
- B channel malfunctions as badly as before
- A channel is something in between.

I also figured out that when I was using linear lab supply, no malfunctions occurred. By default I have been using switching (65kHz) PSUs connected in series, where middle tap is ground.

However, I'm unable to measure any kind of differences in Vcc pins.

Comment: Perhaps image about PCB would be good, issue might not be with the IC itself, but support circuitry.

Comment: You didn't mention thermal compound. Did you put the white goo between the device and the heatsink?

Comment: Seems like the channels are not really identical. Might be construction rather than design (or something like a hair line short). More info such as schematic and photos - there's really no way to help with info given.

Comment: Do all three devices dissipate the same power?

Comment: Are you exceeding the absolute maximum temperatrue, if you are then get a heatsink on those components

Comment: Can you add circuit scheme? Do you have those 3 ICs isolated from heatsink, or they are connected? Are you drawing some current via heatsink and via ICs tab?

Comment: @churpacabras i think we have point here. Thanks to this conversation i started figuring out about tabs being connected to -12V (and heatsink). There is good *separate* supply lines connected to each channel and maybe enough inductance between -12v pins, so that output current dips. Output currents have 120° phase difference (50Hz). Unfortunately i dont dare to upload full schematic here, but once this is confirmed ill put it to answer.

Comment: Are the loads the same?  Perhaps A just has to dissipate more power?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP hasn't modified the question in months and its a debug question.

Comment: @jalaffo - I've done a "copy edit" on your text, to try to improve readability. Please clarify (edit your text) what you mean by "switching (65kHz) PSUs connected series" - do you mean those PSUs are connected *in* series? (if so, wiring diagrams are needed, and also explain why you think series connection is allowed.) Your new results are interesting and seem to be telling us that there are unknown channel differences *somewhere*. The varying results with different PSUs is important. But IMHO *efficient* troubleshooting would need: schematic, access to PCB, interactive scope measurements etc.

Comment: @SamGibson - Pardon me, yes switching psus in series and middle tap is ground. These provide +-12V Vcc lines (Which are bypassed). I have redefined the scope of question but im unable to throw necessary data onto table.

Comment: @jalaffo - Thanks for the clarification about the PSUs. "im unable to throw necessary data onto table" Since that data is secret, unfortunately that confirms my view that this problem does not fit the StackExchange model, due to lack of (public) information & high complexity, which will prevent a definite *answer* being given, except by guessing. I have an idea about the type of problem that *might* be involved, but without the secret info, it would be a waste of time discussing further.

Comment: [cont'd] There seem to be 3 sets of "different behaviours" which "*cry out*" (IMHO) for a troubleshooting methodology like "Problem Analysis" (part of PSDM - Problem Solving and Decision Making) or "Analytical Troubleshooting" (ATS), both from [Kepner-Tregoe](http://www.kepner-tregoe.com/), to be applied. Those 3 sets of differences seem to be: (1) Original config - different channels affected; (2) New config - *changes* to channels affected; (3) New config - different PSUs cause different results.

Comment: [cont'd] Those differences (i.e. "working" vs. "not working" between supposedly identical components) fits *very* well with those methodologies, when more detailed information (which you cannot supply here) is also included. I recommend that you research them and see if anyone involved in your team has been trained in those (or similar) troubleshooting approaches. Perhaps your management would pay for troubleshooting consultancy or to get someone trained, if this problem is serious enough for the business? In my experience, learning those methodologies has been *very* worthwhile. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb, and suggest that you look carefully at your heat sink. You label your 3 units A, B and C, and it's A which gives the problem. I'd guess that you have a single heat sink, and the three units line up on a common extrusion. My guess is that, at the A end of the extrusion, the mounting surface is not perfectly flat. So you're getting tight contact at one side of the IC, but not on the other. This gap is large enough that, even with thermal compound or a Silpad (and you are using one or the other, I hope) the thermal resistance across the gap is much too great.

The defect might be a slight protrusion around the mounting screw, or it might be a bend in the surface. Take a good straight-edge to the area in question, and verify that there is no distortion from a perfectly flat surface. Make sure to check in both axes. It might only take a few thousandths of an inch to be a problem, so be careful.

Comment: That does not really fit with 40°C at the blue spot, which makes contact with the heatsink

Comment: @PlasmaHH - It might, if contact is only being made around the mounting screw. The rest of the package has to channel its heat laterally to the hole.

Comment: at least some rise above the 40°C would be expected since the heat *will* spread from the much hotter part of the tab throughout it a bit

Comment: Heatsink is common for all three channels. There is graphite sheet between surfaces, and i have checked flatness of the surface several times (this was my initial worriy, as it is yours too)